# How to enable button save when all fields and one of the RadioButton and Spinner are checks and fileds in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio

I have 3 editText , for Gender I have RadioGroup and I have one spinner with 4 options. I want to do enable Save Button when all fields are filed and one of RadioButton is chosen and one of spinner is chosen too.
I made setOnCheckListener for three editText with one Watcher but for RadioButton function isChecked (for example female.isChecked()) doesn't work.
How can I do that ?

Comment: Can you provide an example of the code that is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Without a code example I can only provide a generic answer.

Radio buttons should be inside a **Radio Group**. Give the **Radio Group** an id, let's say the id is **gender_radio_group**.

Then give each Radio Button an id, let's say the id's are **male_radio_button** and **female_radio_button**

Now in the code for that view you need to use the following code:

```
RadioGroup genderRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.gender_radio_group);

genderRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) 
       {
          //Get the id of the checked radio button in the group
          int radioButtonID = group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

          //Get the radio button view from the group using the above id
          View radioButton = group.findViewById(radioButtonID);

          //Get whether the button is checked or not
          boolean checked = ((RadioButton) radioButton).isChecked();

          switch(radioButton.getId()) {
            case R.id.male_radio_button:
              if (checked)
              //Do some logic if the male radio button is checked
              break;
            case R.id.female_radio_button:
              if (checked)
              //Do some logic if the female radio button is checked
              break;
          }
       }
});
```

There is another way that this can be done. You can find more details on the Radio Buttons [Official Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/radiobutton).

Answer (score 0):

Assign the radio group checked status an 'int' and use it to in the checking logic. Of course you have to also ensure that the spinner has a listener too. see:

```
RadioGroup genderRadioGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.gender_radio_group);

genderRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int checkedId) 
   {
      //Get the id of the checked radio button in the group
      int radioButtonID = group.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

      //Get the radio button view from the group using the above id
      View radioButton = group.findViewById(radioButtonID);

      //Get whether the button is checked or not
      boolean checked = ((RadioButton) radioButton).isChecked();

      switch(radioButton.getId()) {
        case R.id.male_radio_button:
          if (checked)
           int checkedChecker=1;
          //Do some logic if the male radio button is checked
          break;
        case R.id.female_radio_button:
          if (checked)
           int checkedChecker=1;
          //Do some logic if the female radio button is checked
          break;
      }
   }
   });



  if(editText1.getText.toString.isempty&& 
   editText1.getText.toString.isempty&&
   editText1.getText.toString.isempty&&
   spinnerValue.isempty&&
   intChecker>0){
   saveButton.setEnabled(true);
  }else{
   saveButton.setEnabled(false);
  }
```